# How to manage Entity Framework Contexts with multiple forms

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm having troubles synchronizing my contexts when using multiple forms. Imagine having **ProductsCollectionView** form which holds a list (grid) of products, and **ProductView** form where you edit selected product.

I manage EF contexts lifetime by having a **context per form**, as recommended by MS guidelines.

I found similiar questions here on SO, but none of the answers actually suggested a solution, rather define OP's design as bad and suggest implementing **UnitOfWork/Repository pattern**.

First, I don't see how this can be a solution to this particular problem. And more importantly, wouldn't that be redundant, isn't DbContext itself an UnitOfWork, and DbSet a repository?

One can argue that you can benefit from further abstracting your data access layer by implementing these patterns and making it easier to change EF with something else or supply test data. But that's not the topic.

Back to the question, given the scenario, how would I reflect changes made on a ProductView to ProductCollectionView ?

My best guess would be implementing some sort of mediator and have DbContexts notify it when making changes, and listen for changes from other contexts, then according to changes, act on local data set.

I've been stuck with this for days now. I even saw my cat trying to fix this while I was on a break - no luck. But, to be honest, I don't think it knows how to code. :)

Pointing me to a right direction is great help, providing some code samples/articles is really, really great help :)

Thanks

P.S. Model is built CodeFirst (reverse-engineered).

**EDIT:** Maybe I wasn't clear. My goals is to have ProductsCollectionView updated with the changes made through ProductView after user called SaveChanges() on the ProductView's underlying context . Not restricted only to this scenario, there might be another form opened whose context has this product record loaded and need to reflect the changes made on that record.

Comment: you are looking for something like a messenger service? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276392/creating-a-messenger-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, some sort of mediator/messenger service is best and only solution I found. I'll be happy to learn if someone has come up with something else.

In short:
When saving changes/adding entities, send message/notification and have either ViewModel or Context directly subscribe to messenger and load/reload added/changed entities.